# Flutter Unable to update List<Map<>> datatable onSelectChanged

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, datatable, statefulwidget

Please help - and be patient i am still learning - I have a model with constant data (until I implement my API) that provides Order data

```
class Orders {
  static const List<String> columns = [
    "ID",
    "Items",
    "Total",
    "Status",
  ];

  List<Map<int,String>> header = [
    {0:"Order"},
    {1:"Items"},
    {2:"Total"},
    {3:"Status"},
  ];

  List<Map<String,dynamic>> rows = [
    {"Number":390,"Items":6,"Total":450.00,"Status":"PENDING","Checked":true},
    {"Number":391,"Items":19,"Total":3200.00,"Status":"PENDING","Checked":false},
    {"Number":392,"Items":6,"Total":450.00,"Status":"PENDING","Checked":false},
    {"Number":393,"Items":"-","Total":"-","Status":"-","Checked":false},
  ];

  void setOrderHeader(newHeader){
    header = newHeader;
  }

  void setOrderRows(newRows){
    rows = newRows;
  }

}
```

I then created a DataTable builder which i call on my orders_screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:one/models/orders.dart';

class DataTableBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DataTableBuilderState createState() => _DataTableBuilderState();
}

class _DataTableBuilderState extends State<DataTableBuilder> {
  List<Map<int, String>> get header => Orders().header;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> get rows => Orders().rows;
    int sortColumnIndex = 0;
    bool sort = true;
    String rowKey = "Number";

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        int col = 0;

        return SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            child: DataTable(
                sortAscending: sort,
                sortColumnIndex: sortColumnIndex,
                showCheckboxColumn: true,
                columns: header.map((e) => DataColumn(
                    label: _getStyledText(e[col++]!.toUpperCase(),14,Colors.black),
                ),
                ).toList(),
                rows: rows.map(((rowData) => DataRow(
                    cells: <DataCell>[
                        DataCell(
                            _getStyledText(
                                rowData["Number"],
                                12,
                                Colors.black87,
                            ),
                        ), //Extracting from Map element the value
                        DataCell(
                            _getStyledText(
                                rowData["Items"],
                                16,
                                Colors.black87,
                            ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                            _getStyledText(
                                rowData["Total"],
                                12,
                                Colors.black87,
                            ),
                        ),
                        DataCell(
                            _getStyledText(
                                rowData["Status"],
                                12,
                                Colors.deepOrange,
                            ),
                            // showEditIcon:true,
                            placeholder: true,
                        ),
                    ],
                    selected: rowData["Checked"],
                    onSelectChanged: (selected) {
                        if (selected==true) {
                            onSelectedRow(selected!, rowData,rows);
                            print(rows);
                        }
                    },
                )),
                ).toList(),
            ),
        );
  }

    Widget _getStyledText(dynamic rowText,double size, Color bgColor) {
        return Text(
            rowText.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: size==0?14:size,
                color: bgColor,
            ),
        );
    }

    onSelectedRow(bool selected, Map<String,dynamic> rowData,List<Map<String,dynamic>> rows) async {
        if (selected) {
            for(int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                if(rows[i]["Number"] == rowData["Number"]){
                    setState(() {
                        rows[i]["Checked"] = true;
                        Orders().setOrderRows(rows);
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is with the `onSelectChanged()` and `setState()` methods - I would like to update the orders list to set the selected row to be checked or unchecked.

I am able to update the order data in the `onSelectedRow()` method but it does not seem to update my global rows variable or the `setState()` method is not updating the table.

Comment: Do you mean it does not update the values in your `Orders` class?

Comment: Yes i would like to change the values and update the data table - I understand that i have provided the values and they are basically constant